# random_bytes function is not working in CI 3, PHP 7.2

Tags: codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-3

My Cpanel based server is running on PHP 7.2 using Codieigniter 3.x

```
public function fxnname()
{
    return random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_SECRETBOX_KEYBYTES);
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Call to undefined function random_bytes()

in my custom library code which is placed inside `public_html/application/libraries/mycustomlibrary.php`
I tried to google and this function should have worked in PHP 7.2. Is there any library/helper which I am missing in autoload or something else is required to be done?

Comment: Have You enable the libsodium extension on PHP?

Comment: @SilumanSupra Yes, I had a word with the web hosting provider and they have enabled the libsodium extension. Still random_bytes() doesnt work. Howeever, if I run the same in a regular php file insead of codeigniter custom library, it runs fine. So this issue is with some codeigniter setting rather than server

Comment: isn't the CI function `get_random_bytes()`?

Comment: random_bytes is part of the PHP core since version 7 (i.e. it does not require an extension). Disabling it in php.ini with `disable_functions` gives a different error. You must be running PHP 5. Check the output of `phpversion()`.